# Problem using Javascript to redirect to a URL with a query string

Tags: php, javascript

#### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Edit(id)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure to edit?")==true)
    {
        location.href='employee_set.php&edit='+id;
    }
}
</script>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["edit"])==false) {
    echo "no response";
} else {
    echo "link success";
}
?>
```

My problem is the Javascript is OK. The location href example. http://localhost/employee_set.php&edit=30 ...

The PHP code is not working. Error is not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
location.href='employee_set.php&edit='+id;
```

should be

```
location.href='employee_set.php?edit='+id;
```